# Conversion of console app code to Windows Form code in VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, console, google-drive-api

every one. I humbly want to ask for your support on this.
I am doing my best trying to learn the Google Drive SDK and have followed all the steps provided in the video as well as on the page:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-cs

I have however come to halt as I realize the sample code provided is CSharp and no VB version.
I've tried converting it to VB using the Telerik converter but the results are not encouraging as I still see curly brackets in there and what not. I know I see those,because  its a console App and I will be sincere that Im not quite good at console app code.

I therefore humbly seek assistance on how to convert this already converted C# to VB code
to a Windows Form version. Thank you.

```
Namespace GoogleDriveSamples
    Class DriveCommandLineSample
        Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
            Dim credential As UserCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets() With { _
                Key .ClientId = "CLIENT_ID_HERE", _
                Key .ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET_HERE" _
            }, New () {DriveService.Scope.Drive}, "user", CancellationToken.None).Result

            ' Create the service.
            Dim service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
                Key .HttpClientInitializer = credential, _
                Key .ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample" _
            })

            Dim body As New File()
            body.Title = "My document"
            body.Description = "A test document"
            body.MimeType = "text/plain"

            Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("document.txt")
            Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray)

            Dim request As FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain")
            request.Upload()

            Dim file As File = request.ResponseBody
            Console.WriteLine("File id: " + file.Id)
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end this process.")
            Console.ReadLine()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

Drive SDK (or any other google SDK) does not currently support vb. Use c#/.net to do so or if you must, do the https calls (put get post etc) directly from any language even vb.

Comment: If it supports C#, how could it *not* support VB.NET?

Comment: does support vb.net, but thats not what you said in your question, you said just "vb" which implies the older visual basic.

Comment: Well, the sample code provided in the question doesn't imply that. And Microsoft does, in fact, market VB.NET as simply "VB" quite often. It really is time to move on from VB 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Infer On

Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Services

Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Dim secrets = New ClientSecrets()
    secrets.ClientId = "CLIENT_ID_HERE"
    secrets.ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"

    Dim scope = New List(Of String)
    scope.Add(DriveService.Scope.Drive)

    Dim credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, scope, "user", CancellationToken.None).Result()

    Dim initializer = New BaseClientService.Initializer
    initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential
    initializer.ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample"

    Dim service = New DriveService(initializer)

    Dim body = New File
    body.Title = "My document"
    body.Description = "A test document"
    body.MimeType = "text/plain"

    Dim byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\MyFile.txt")
    Dim stream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray)

    Dim request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain")
    request.Upload()

    body = request.ResponseBody
    MessageBox.Show("The File id is:" & body.Id, "Upload Succeeded")
End Sub

End Class
```